# Discord.JS - Building a Discord Bot Authorisation System

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, authorization, roles

I was building a discord bot that once you authorise it to your account, it gives you a verified role on my server.

How could I go about checking if a discord bot is authorised to someone's account please. I am using Discord.JS.
Here is my existing code:
index.js:

```
const { Client, Events, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');
const { Collection } = require('discord.js')

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds] });
client.commands = new Collection();

const foldersPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFolders = fs.readdirSync(foldersPath);

for (const folder of commandFolders) {
    const commandsPath = path.join(foldersPath, folder);
    const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of commandFiles) {
        const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
        const command = require(filePath);
        // Set a new item in the Collection with the key as the command name and the value as the exported module
        if ('data' in command && 'execute' in command) {
            client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
        } else {
            console.log(`[WARNING] The command at ${filePath} is missing a required "data" or "execute" property.`);
        }
    }
}

client.on(Events.InteractionCreate, async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isChatInputCommand()) return;

    const command = interaction.client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) {
        console.error(`No command matching ${interaction.commandName} was found.`);
        return;
    }

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        if (interaction.replied || interaction.deferred) {
            await interaction.followUp({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
        } else {
            await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks for any advice you can provide and even to let me know if this is possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "checking if a discord bot is authorised to someone's account", please be more descriptive in what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Dan So when you follow a discord bot link, which is generated through the URL Generator tab of your Discord Bot in your Discord Dev Portal, when it gets to the screen that acknowledges all the permissions, how can I use the discord.js package to check if that user has clicked 'authorise this bot'